# CorePHP - Insert multiple dynamic rows in Database using single query

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm appending the table fields by Jquery. In the table row input fields are set. I want to insert the value of that inserted rows in database. Those fields are populated by the user and I want to make it dynamic. Can someone suggest me how to make the procedre

Comment: You can create a query like this: `INSERT INTO some_table (col1, col2) VALUES ('val1-1', 'val1-2'), ('val2-1', 'val2-2'), ('val3-1', 'val3-2'), ...and so on`. If that's not what you want, then you need to edit your question with the related code and explain a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get familiar with jQuery's `$.ajax` function for sending requests. You'll also need to make an API with at least one endpoint for saving. I recommend a single endpoint that takes the id and data you'd like to save. Then you can just provide that `onchange` for any of the inputs.